# How to add class to particular li with anchor tag?

Tags: jquery

this is very simple thing.I know and i am always using this type of thing. Now in my one project I am facing problem add class.

bellow is just HTML example:

```
//html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#waxing" class="st_tab">Waxing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#hair-design" class="st_tab">Hair Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#chemical-services" class="st_tab">Chemical Services</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js

```
$("ul li a:nth-child(1)").addClass("st_first_tab");
```

see this http://jsfiddle.net/QbN7c/1/ but it's working fine i use like this

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("st_first_tab");
```

i mean with out **a** tag.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").find('a:first').addClass("st_first_tab");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishkumarshr/QbN7c/2/)

Comment: That would be the same as `$("ul li:nth-child(1) a").addClass("st_first_tab");`

Comment: what if there are multiple `<a>` tags?

Comment: Same as `$("ul li:nth-child(1) a").addClass("st_first_tab");` There's no multiple `<a>` tags in current  scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1) a:first ").addClass("st_first_tab"); //first li
$("ul li:nth-child(3) a:first ").addClass("st_first_tab"); //third li
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/softvar/QbN7c/5/)